# How to write my own functions for comparison?

Tags: c++

I wrote a function for vector comparison.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;

bool mycomp(const vector<int>& vi_a, const vector<int>& vi_b){
    for(auto x:vi_a) cout << x;
    cout << '\n';
    return true;
}

int main(){
    vector<int> vi1{2,9,8};
    vector<int> vi2{3,5,6};
    vector<int> vi = min(vi1, vi2, mycomp);
    for(auto x:vi) cout << x;
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
356
356
```

What's weird is that the output is `356`, instead of `298`. It seems that the two vectors are switched when calling `mycomp`.

p.s. I'd rather not use lambda here, because `mycomp` contains more than one line of code, which is more readable this way.

Comment: Your function always returns true. `min` will just return whatever it considers the left hand side.

Comment: Your question is unclear; the example code prints a vector to `cout` in two different places, but you only comment on one output.

Comment: I suggest making this into a [mcve] by adding the missing headers, using directives, and expected and observed output.

Comment: I turned it into an [mcve].

Comment: You're not fulfilling the [requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) for the comparison function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the [cppreference documentation for `std::min()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjGy-yVwPHUAhXJLo8KHXg0CssQFgglMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.cppreference.com%2Fw%2Fcpp%2Falgorithm%2Fmin&usg=AFQjCNFSZGzowiTseWRG3FjFZd2sIbgUEA) you will see in the possible implementation that the second element is used as the first element in the comparator.

```
template<class T, class Compare> 
const T& min(const T& a, const T& b, Compare comp)
{
    return (comp(b, a)) ? b : a;
}
```

And when you call `min()` with the arguments `vi2` and `vi1`, the second argument is passed to the comparator (which in your case is `vi2`), upon which the comparator returns true (implying that `vi2` is the minimum of the two).  While doing this the comparator also prints out `356` because that is the first element passed to the comparator according to the possible implementation above.

After that happens you take the presumably smaller of the two vectors, which is the first one passed to the comparator according to the possible implementation above (which is `vi2`).  And you print that out.  Therefore you get `356` again.

---

Note that the reason `b` is passed as the first argument to `std::min` is because in the case where the two compare equal the algorithm is required to return `a`.  At the same time it is required to call the comparator only once.  Combining these two requirements gives the possible implementation above.

Comment: The last paragraph alone makes the entire answer.